# How to store numbers in an array of structs

Tags: c, arrays, struct, double, scanf

Hey so I have the string below:

```
char teststring[50] = "A 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0";
```

I have lots of strings in this format and I need to store just the numbers (not the letter) together. All the numbers are related so I have been trying to make an array of structs but am having some trouble. I set up the struct like this (named the file wall.h and included it in the main file)

```
struct example{
    double x1;
    double y1;
    double x2; 
    double y2;
};
```

Then declared an array of 14 structs using

```
struct example ex[14];
```

Then Im trying to use this to scan the values from the string and store them in the first struct in the array

```
sscanf(teststring, "A %f %f %f %f", &ex[0].x1, &ex[0].y1, &ex[0].x2, &ex[0].y2);
```

However it doesnt seem to work and tells me that the value is 0.00000 when i go to print, instead of 1.0

Comment: Is `$f` intentional or typo? Should be `%f`

Comment: That was a typo sorry!

Answer (score 5):

Undefined behaviour manifests as `0.0` in you case today.
Calling scanf with incorrect arguments is an undefined behaviour. In your case you are telling comiler that argument types are `float *` but passing `double *` instead.

You should use `"%lf"` to read `double`.

```
sscanf(teststring, "A %lf %lf %lf %lf", &ex[0].x1, &ex[0].y1, &ex[0].x2, &ex[0].y2);
/*                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                               */
```

`"%f"` is used for reading (using `scanf` family of functions) and printing (using `printf` family of functions) `float` and printing `double`. (It works for `float` because of automatic promotion of arguments in variadic function. Automatic promotion is not possible from pointer of one type to pointer of other type for example `float *` to `double *`).
`"%lf"` is used for reading and writing `double`.

So summarizing:

```
+--------+--------------+---------------+
|  type  | scanf family | printf family |
+--------+--------------+---------------+
| float  | %f           | %f            | 
+--------+--------------+---------------+
| double | %lf          | %f or %lf     |
+--------+--------------+---------------+
Using %lf in printf to print float would work but can be misleading to other readers
```

Comment: It works now! Thanks so much! Do I use that for printing double as well?

Comment: @nextgenben99 It is optional for printing double. Let me add this extra info in answer in a nice tabular format.